# How to open one (or more) gnome-terminal window with few tabs, each with different profile, when start/reboot the computer?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, configuration, tabs

I have several profile for terminal. I can open all profiles on boot **but** they open in different windows with this cmd in startup applications:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=ablack && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=agreeen && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=aubergine && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=beige && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=cyan && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=grey && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=orange && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=white && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=yellow && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=ablack
```

I tried to open one window with several tabs with this cmd without success:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=ablack && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=agreeen && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=aubergine && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=beige && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=cyan && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=grey && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=orange && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=white && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=yellow && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=ablack
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To open a `gnome-terminal` window with few tabs we should use the option `--tab`. See `gnome-terminal --help-all`. Also in `man gnome-terminal` we can find this explanation:

```
--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME
     Open a new window containing a tab with the given profile. 
     More than one of these options can be provided.
--tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME
     Open a tab in the window with the given profile. 
     More than one of these options can be provided, to open several tabs.
```

So, to open `gnome-terminal` window with few tabs, we should use command as this one:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=ProfileA --tab-with-profile=ProfileB --tab-with-profile=ProfileC
```

Compose your own command and test it into a terminal. If it works satisfactorily add it as an entry in [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login):

[image]

There are few possible approaches how to open few `gnome-terminal` windows with few tabs in each. I would suggest to use a command as follow:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=ProfileA --tab-with-profile=ProfileB && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=ProfileC --tab-with-profile=ProfileD
```

Another idea is to create separate Startup Applications entry for each `gnome-terminal` window.

Comment: @mamesaye, what happened, when you tried it?

Comment: nothing happen on reboot. So I tried `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=ablack --tab-with-profile=agreen && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=aubergine && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=beige && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=cyan && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=grey  && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=orange  && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=white  && gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=yellow` and it worked on reboot.

Comment: @mamesaye I will update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: It should be one single `gnome-terminal` command with multiple `--tab-with-profile` (or `--tab` and `--profile`) options.

Comment: Each `gnome-terminal` command, even when `--tab` is used, opens a new _window_ because it has no way of knowing which existing window you want the new tab to appear in. Only if you have multiple `--tab` options then they open tabs in the same new window.

Comment: @mamesaye , I've updated the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed confusing (you're not the first hitting this issue), the docs should be made more explicit.